# Android 12 Precise vs Approximate Location Permissions Dialog

Tags: android, permissions, location

Can anyone confirm consistency around the requesting UX for fine location permissions on Android 12?

Using EasyPermissions, when requesting Location for...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
targetSdkVersion 30
compileSdkVersion 30
```

..we see one device use the new precise / approximate dialog, and another the legacy dialog.  Only tangible difference is the Pixel 3 is on a slightly newer build of Android 12.  For what it's worth, once compiling and targeting SDK 31, the two phones act consistently.

Related, but not noticed here, is an article describing variation for needing fine+coarse permissions on Android 12 - https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request

Pixel 3a XL:

[image][image]

Pixel 3:

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

After some renewed digging, it seems Google just made a mistake.  I haven't dug into OSS code, but on early versions of Android 12, Google must not be checking `targetSdkVersion == 31` when determining to display the new dialog style.

Once I target SDK 31, both Pixel devices act the same and use the new dialog style.

Comment: Can you show some official link or google issue about this, I also facing this one but can't find anything though

Comment: Aye no official documentation, but we noted this at scale within Uber.  The issue no longer occurs as any Android 12 device we have has received subsequent updates.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, starting from Android 11 (SDK level 30), the permission model has changed and now the users are given more control over their privacy. The OS shows different dialogs for requesting fine location permissions based on the purpose of the app. If the app needs the location information for only a short period of time, the OS shows an approximate location dialog. If the app needs location information for a longer period of time, the OS shows a precise location dialog.

So it seems that the consistency around the requesting UX for fine location permissions depends on the Android version, the device, and the build of the Android OS. It could also be affected by the library used to request the permissions, such as EasyPermissions.

Compiling and targeting the SDK version 31 may help in achieving consistency, but it's better to always check the behavior on different devices to ensure the proper functioning of the app.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33818401)